# Automatically appearing contact form like Kiss Insight?

Tags: forms, contact-page

I have been using Kiss Insight which is great to collect customers' feedbacks. However, this is only an one-way communication because we can't answer some of customers concerns.

Is there any hosted solution that works like Kiss Insight but allows customers to enter their email and you can reply back?

Answer (score 1):

[UserVoice](http://www.uservoice.com/) provides a similar widget, but for more detailed comments, and even full-on support if you want.